# Кастомные клавиатуры Telegram

Tags: telegram-bot

Возможно ли передать  такую кастомную клавиатуру, которая при нажатии на кнопку будет передавать в чат текст, отличный от текста на самой кнопке клавиатуры?
Цель этой задачи: разнообразить общение с ботом(текстовый квест).

Comment: Как насчёт [InlineKeyboards](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardmarkup)?

Answer (score 2):

Вот на php:

```
<?php
$access_token = 'xxx';
$api = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' . $access_token;
$output = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), TRUE);
$chat_id = $output['message']['chat']['id'];
$first_name = $output['message']['chat']['first_name'];
$message = $output['message']['text'];
$callback_query = $output['callback_query'];
$data = $callback_query['data'];
$message_id = ['callback_query']['message']['message_id'];
$chat_id_in = $callback_query['message']['chat']['id'];
switch($message) {
    case '/test':  
    $inline_button1 = array("text"=>"Google url","url"=>"http://google.com");
    $inline_button2 = array("text"=>"work plz","callback_data"=>'/plz');
    $inline_keyboard = [[$inline_button1,$inline_button2]];
    $keyboard=array("inline_keyboard"=>$inline_keyboard);
    $replyMarkup = json_encode($keyboard); 
     sendMessage($chat_id, "ok", $replyMarkup);
    break;
}
switch($data){
    case '/plz':
    sendMessage($chat_id_in, "plz");
    break;
}
function sendMessage($chat_id, $message, $replyMarkup) {
  file_get_contents($GLOBALS['api'] . '/sendMessage?chat_id=' . $chat_id . '&text=' . urlencode($message) . '&reply_markup=' . $replyMarkup);
}
```

на кнопке написано *work plz*, но при нажатии будет вызываться команда */plz*. Однако если просто написать команду */plz*, то бот ничего не ответит.